# APScheduler Using Flask python

Tags: flask, apscheduler

DEBUG:apscheduler.scheduler:Next wakeup is due at 2019-12-19 12:24:50.010070+08:00 (in 4.996792 seconds)

I always get this error when i run my job. It just happen when i'm using a million of data in database but when i'm using the thousand of data it run smoothly w/o this error.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that if problem occurs when the data becomes larger, then APScheduler can miss the job due to long time the data processing takes.

You can try:

- Moving your job start to the very end of method and place it right before response
- Add `misfire_grace_time` parameter when you start your job (for example `misfire_grace_time=5000`)